# How to append value dynamically to curl command in shell script

Tags: shell

I am implementing shell script to make API call using curl when I need to append username dynamically it is not working as expected.

Here is the scenario:

VAR_USER_NAME="myname"

curl 'http://localhost:8080/api?username="${VAR_USER_NAME}"'

But the username is not fetching properly.

Comment: variable expansion doesn't work in single quotes.  What happens with `curl "http://localhost:8080/api?username=\"${VAR_USER_NAME}\""`

Comment: Run your code with `set -x`. It will show you how the commands are expanded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issues is fixed by just adding double quotes(")instead of single quotes to url

curl "http://localhost:8080/api?username=${VAR_USER_NAME}"